# Java Generics - Erasures Mechanism

Tags: java, generics, type-erasure

Say.., the Java compiler erases all type info, and replaces all occurrences of those with their upper bounds (if mentioned) or Object..

My questions is: no insertion of casts takes place here. Casting occurs later when some other class is compiled against this type info-free class, where, depending on the type argument(s) that other class supplements, the generic class is recompiled (for a second time) and all casts are put in place and the class is ready for run time.., right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the class is not recompiled. The casts happen on the boundary between concrete and generic types.

If you're trying to figure it out, you could look at using a generic class as a raw type (i.e. without the generics). For instance `ArrayList`:

```
List l = new ArrayList(); // An `ArrayList<String>` before generics.

l.add("Hello");
String s = (String) l.get(0);
```

The casts are inserted where the concrete type is known (`String` in this case). They are *not* inserted inside the `ArrayList` class, and there isn't really a need for that.

Comment: Thanks. So the casts are really within the user class, not the generic class, right? Also, referring to your example above, the cast to String which was explicitly inserted there would've been automatically inserted by the Java compiler if we specified List<String>, right?

Comment: @Searcherer Yes the casts are in the user's class. The erasure of `ArrayList`'s type parameter is `Object`, but only in the user class you need a more specific type, so that's where you cast. And yes, that cast is automatically inserted in the case of `ArrayList<String>`. Note that there is no cast for the `add` method.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I just wish to ask one last little thing: regarding your note about there being no cast for the  add method, the compiler still chicks the argument supplied against the signature of add, which may vary based on the type parameter, and hence refuse invalid args. right?

Comment: @Searcherer Yes, the compiler checks the argument against the generic type (if there is one), but there is no check at runtime, while there _is_ one for `get`.

Answer (score 0):

> Casting occurs later when some other class is compiled against this
>   type info-free class,

No, the cast is performed during the compilation phase of the class itself.
The compiled class should not change according to the classes that depends on.

Look at this method :

```
public class TestCast {

    public void doSomething(){
       List<Integer> values = new ArrayList<>();
       values.add(1);
       Integer value = values.get(0);
    }
}
```

Here is the disassembly method of the `TestCast` compiled class (done with `javap` tool):

```
public void doSomething();
   Code:
      0: new           #15                 // class java/util/ArrayList
      3: dup
      4: invokespecial #17                 // Method java/util/ArrayList."<init>":()V
      7: astore_1
      8: aload_1
      9: iconst_1
     10: invokestatic  #18                 // Method java/lang/Integer.valueOf:(I)Ljava/lang/Integer;
     13: invokeinterface #24,  2           // InterfaceMethod java/util/List.add:(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z
     18: pop
     19: aload_1
     20: iconst_0
     21: invokeinterface #30,  2           // InterfaceMethod java/util/List.get:(I)Ljava/lang/Object;
     26: checkcast     #19                 // class java/lang/Integer
     29: astore_2
     30: return
```

The cast is indeed added by the compiler :

```
 26: checkcast     #19                 // class java/lang/Integer
```

Answer (score 0):

Something no other answer mentioned so far are bridge methods.

e.g.

```
public class GenericTest implements Comparable<GenericTest>{

    @Override
    public int compareTo(GenericTest o) {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

The Compiler will actually create two methods. `int compareTo(Object);` that casts and forwards and the expected `int compareTo(GenericTest)`